# Produce only one validation message for a column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am now trying to develop api in rails. I want to display validation message for the field *email* and *houseno* field .In my model I have added the below code for validation of email

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i}, uniqueness: true
validates :email_confirmation, presence: true, if: :not_recovering_password, on: :create
validates :email, confirmation: true, email_format: {message: 'Invalid E-mail address'}, if: :not_recovering_password, on: :create
```

validation for houseno

```
validates :houseno,    presence: true, numericality: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 3}
```

But when I give an empty string for houseno and email. It produced multiple validation error.

```
   "errors": {
"email": [
  "Please enter your e-mail address",
  "There is an error in the input value of"
],  
"houseno": [
  "Please enter a houseno",
  "Please enter a numeric value is",
  "Please enter three or more characters"
],
```

How can I get only the first validation message. Please help to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your model has an attribute `errors`. This object contains all errors. If you want a specific error you can use `object.errors[:email]` to get an array of errors for a field. You can access the first error message for a fieldvia `object.errors[:email].first`. You can check if an error for a specific field exists with `object.errors.include?(:email)`